# s3 Presigned urls without bucket policy does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is what I have tried.

Lambda code:

```
import uuid

import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the service client.
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    # Generate a random S3 key name
    upload_key = uuid.uuid4().hex

    # Generate the presigned URL for put requests
    presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='put_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': 'test',
            'Key': upload_key,
            'ContentType': 'image/png',
            'ACL': 'public-read'
        }
    )

    # Return the presigned URL
    return {
        "upload_url": presigned_url
    }
```

### CORS policy for s3 bucket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I have tried  to upload objects from curl command

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:image/png" -H "public-read" --upload-file ~/Downloads/newlogo.png "presignedurl"
```

if a public write access is given for the bucket I am able to successfully upload the objects in s3 if not I am getting an access denied 403 exceptions I have gone through most of StackOverflow post not able to figure out the issue please guide me any help is highly appreciated

I am also planning to use this for a website which uploads media files to the s3 bucket using pre-signed URLs .what is the best way to handle authentication for it?

The error i am getting

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>73881648C31D9316</RequestId><HostId>g4BuDVC7XZKLkAwpvztjqDC4GW9y5s9nk+vu1TsLQBl2XeXQOtOeFR+0hmJn0fjW5xkYeAE3pfA=</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: Does your lambda function have permission to write to the s3 bucket?

Comment: @cementblocks No i am just generating presigned URLs from lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create pre-signed a url for s3 put object (or any other api call) that signed request uses the credentials that the SDK is configured with, in this case your lambda's role. Give your Lambda's IAM role write access to this s3 bucket  and your uploads will succeed.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you

Comment: I gave Lamba S3 full access but still it is not working

Comment: please check the question

Comment: If I add policy to S3 bukcet for public write it is working but I don't want to do that

Comment: Is curl performing a PUT or a POST? It needs to be a PUT. Add `-X PUT`. This is what I have used to upload to signed urls. `curl -X PUT -T filename -H 'Content-type: image/png' signedUrl`